# Get a table column of type string as separate values in a Listbox while bounding the listbox

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, listbox

Alright, I have something in mind which I think is nearly impossible, but to be sure I thought lets ask it.

I have multiple records in my Access Table (linked with SQL server) which are of type nvarchar a.k.a. String.

I have a table called Orders and I want to specify if those Orders are of some type. For example Iv'e got the orders **A**, **B**, **C** and **D**. Then I have got the types **A1**, **A2**, **A3** and **A4** (which are from another table - lets call it Types). 
Order A can have type A1, A3 and A4, while order B can have types A2, A3 and order C can only have type A3.

I want to easily be able to click in my access form which types are valid for a specific order, if I just had these 4 types it would be easy since I could just make four BIT (yes/no) Table fields which represent the Types, though in reality there are 34 types and about 900 orders and adding 34 table fields is a bit crazy.

So I thought lets make the Types a string input and use a splitter character for separation. So then I just have to add 1 extra table field and for each order I can then add the types as a string like so: 
Order A = Types A1;A3;A4 (the ; is used as the splitter here).

The downside of this is that this can't be easily edited in an access form and doesn't look that nice. Checkboxes for example look much better and are way more easier to click on / off for the specifying part.

So my idea was:
Use a listbox, get all the available types as a string and add every type separately into the listbox by using a foreach on the ;

This works, though the downside (again) is that it now can't have a ControlSource/Rowsource which means, if you select 1 'Type' in the listbox for a specific order, all the orders will select that Type (because it is unbound..). The form has to be a continuous form.

Is there a way to bound my string with Types to the Order? If there is I can return, with some sort of function/event, the selected type and add it to the string (or remove it from the string) in the SQL server for the specific Order.

Comment: Is there any correlation between the Orders / Types at all? For example, you said Order A can be type A1, A3, A4 - are these just distinct values with no correlation to the Order name?

Comment: There is indeed no correlation, the correlation is the thing I am trying to achieve now. Some more information: a company has 6/7 workers. These workers are divided under 3 divisions. These 3 divisions have there own Types but some Types overlap. Orders are usual Division specific, though some Orders can also have overlap (for example 1 order can be for 2 divisions so the order has all the types for those 2 divisions).